# Create pdf file of Activity screen in Android

Tags: android, pdf, ondraw

Recently i have learned about [Android PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) and i can create a pdf file of a activity screen that looks like the same as screen. Now i need to create pdf file from multiple screen. Suppose i have a activity for displaying one user profile information. From this Activity i can create pdf file of this screen which is for one user but i need a pdf file of all user screen. That means when i press a button from that Activity, for all the user the UI should be updated and create a [Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.Page.html) for each UI.The first page of pdf for 1st user screen 2nd page for 2nd user screen and so on.

I have tried to update the UI for each user and create [Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.Page.html) for pdf file but i am missing some text. Another problem arise when i setVisibility of a view to GONE/VISIABLE then some view are missing in pdf file . I have to setVisibility because some information is blank for some user. From first user to end user a view may be several times visibility changed.

Step:

```
for each user 
   // start a page
   Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
   updateUI()   // this function may change text and visibility of a view
   contentView.draw(page.getCanvas());

   // finish the page
   document.finishPage(page);
```

But from this upper code  sometime i am missing some text and view

I also tried to inflate the views from xml and added to the activity so that i can keep separate reference of View for all user UI.

Step:

1. I inflate view
2. Remove previous child of parent view
3. Add information in inflate view
4. Add inflate view to parent view
5. then make a page of pdf

   Used below code to create pdf

   ```
   for each user
     // start a page
     Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
     create inflateView
     add information to inflatedView
     remove child of the parentView
     add inflatedView to the parentView
     // draw something on the page
     parentView.draw(page.getCanvas());
     // finish the page
     document.finishPage(page);
   ```

From this code the updated view(parentView) is blank in the created pdf . I think the views are not drawn intime.

How can i solve this problem. As [Android PdfDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.Page.html) is new i can't find any solution of this.